# how to fix sqlite3 errors while trying to implement my DBAccess class

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am working on my database access class thats trying to make calls to the DB with sqlite3 functions but I am getting all of these errors, I'm just woundering if anyone has experienced these kinda of errors before or if they have any idea as to why they might be occurring.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess getAllMakes] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess initalizeDatabase] in DBAccess.o
      -[DBAccess closeDatabase] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess getAllMakes] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess getAllMakes] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess getAllMakes] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess initalizeDatabase] in DBAccess.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[DBAccess initalizeDatabase] in DBAccess.o
      -[DBAccess closeDatabase] in DBAccess.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Okay Its because I havent added the sqlite framework.. or something to that effect just figuring out which framework I have to add now.. Will post an update once I have figured it out.

Comment: So I ended up having to add libsqlite3.0.dylib framework and all the errors went :) thats a great feeling lol.

Answer (score 5):

Add framework libsqlite3.0.dylib to your project in frameworks